# How to output from mysql base as json?

Tags: php

i tried this code
but I can't

```
$row=$dbconnection->prepare ("select * from  fa");

$row->execute();

$data=array();

foreach ($row as $result)
{
    $data['movies'] = $result;
    array_push ($data, $isonformat);
}

echo json_encode ($data);   
?>
```

result

```
{"movies":{"name":"5","0":"5"},"0":null}
```

what I want {"movies": [ {  "name":"5"} ] }

Comment: `$isonformat` ? Where does that come from

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `array_push()` and add an `[]` to the `$data['movies'] = $result;` to create a sub array

Also add

```
$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

or

```
$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to stop the resultset returning both object/array and numeric reference to each column. One of these should really be part of the connection script

```
$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$row=$dbconnection->prepare ("select * from  fa");
$row->execute();

$data=array();

foreach ($row as $result) {
    $data['movies'][] = $result;
}

echo json_encode ($data);
```

**Alternatively**

```
$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$row = $db->prepare ("select * from  articles");
$row->execute();

$data = [];

$data['movies'] = $row->fetchAll();
echo json_encode ($data);
```

Comment: An alternative would be to skip the foreach loop and just do: `$data['movies'] = $row->fetchAll();`

Comment: @M.Eriksson is correct, that would also work, answer amended accordingly, Thanks M

Comment: '$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$row = $db->prepare ("select * from  articles");
$row->execute();

$data = [];

$data['movies'] = $row->fetchAll();
echo json_encode ($data);   '


error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $data = [];
please tell me what i did wrong

Comment: Replace with `$data = array();` I assume you must be using a very old version of PHP

Comment: You might consider upgrading to PHP 8

Comment: Thanks, but another mistake Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in

Comment: Oh of course, that line need to go after the connection, amended the code

Comment: yes it happened.how to remove "0":"212"? I want to receive{"movies":[{"name":"212"}]}

Comment: Sorry, was that a question, or were you saying that it now works and removed the numeric array?

Comment: It's a question

Comment: how to delete a number array?

Comment: Adding this line `$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` should have done that

Comment: Maybe my database doesn't support this feature.

Comment: can it be done in another way?

Comment: Please show the JSON you are getting

Comment: Its a feature of the PDO Extension rather than the database

Comment: Ahhh solved it, it has to be run before the `prepare()` for it to take effect